# Excellence on society

Tags: interviewing, applications

"Our scholarship programme's motto is excellence. How would you reflect this on society?"

I have been asked this question for a scholarship application I am applying for. Generally the questions are more oriented towards your specific domain of study or regarding your research experience. So I can somehow answer them.

I am not sure, what they actually mean by "reflect excellence on society". If anyone here has any clue regarding it. Do let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a phrase that is good for bullshit bingo. I'd just take the buzzwords they want to hear, add some positive adjectives and auxiliary verbs and run that through a spellchecker.

Comment: Is that an exact quote? Maybe this needs to go to [english.se], because as a native speaker I cannot get any sense out of it.

Comment: Dear @AakashM. Yes this is an exact quote. I have copy pasted it from the application form.

Comment: @AakashM I think they mean _given that you're accepted and successfully graduate from our program, how would you apply our "program motto" onto your work to the benefit of society?_ I'm not a native speaker, and it's still a stupid question, but there we go.

Comment: I would just answer it with some stuff about how I strive for excellence and have achieved it in the past, and would continue to do so.  With specific examples as possible.  But it's a dumb question.  I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: "*Please feel free to share your thoughts.*" You're looking for a forum, not a Q&A site. VTC.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thank you for pointing out. I have removed that line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because language comprehension has nothing to do with the workplace.

Comment: I can see most of the people commenting here are experienced users. You are allowed to downvote this question or vote it as off-topic. But I have also seen this question on Quora regarding as an interview question. And from the main page of workplace "to get answers on topics such as the job hunting process, interviewing".

Comment: "*Quora*" You are *definitely* on the wrong site. Please check the [help] for details on the types of questions we can answer here. A question about what statement X means on document Y at company Z is *never* on-topic here.

Comment: By reflect I think they want you to write how you will give excellence "back" to society. e.g. you will work hard and make a good mark on society. Now expand that into a nice sounding essay.

Comment: Are questions about a scholarship application considered on-topic here? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with work?

Answer (score 3):

I would say they're looking at you answering some sort of platitudinous tripe about 'being the best you can be' and 'delivering only the highest standard of work at the absolute pinnacle of professionalism' or some such.